# how to change text when i click list item in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]
When I select the picker, it is changing all the list. I want to change only selected item. I am using react native list... for example, I select 5 in picker it is changing in all the row in list. I have tried so many methods.

Here is the code:

```
    {
      list.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <Picker style={{ color: 'black' }}
            selectedValue={this.state.subject}
            // onValueChange={(subject,i) => { this.setState({ subject: subject }) }}
            onValueChange={this.onPicker}                              >
            <Picker.Item label="Enter Quantity" value="Enter Quantity" />
            <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
            <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
            <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
            <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
            <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
            <Picker.Item label="6" value="6" />
            <Picker.Item label="7" value="7" />
            <Picker.Item label="8" value="8" />
            <Picker.Item label="9" value="9" />
            <Picker.Item label="10" value="10" />
          </Picker>
        );
      })
    }

export const list = [
  {
    Farmer_Name: 'Ramlal',
    Farmer_Location: 'Karimnagar',
    Cultivation_Method: 'Organic',
    Harvest_Date: '29 Aug 2018 to 5 Sep 2018',
    Variety: 'Arka Lohit',
    Pesticide_Residue_Index: 'Below EPA Tolerance',
    NoofOrdersProcessedforThisForm: '5',

  },
  {
    Farmer_Name: 'Ajit gopal',
    Farmer_Location: 'Warangal',
    Cultivation_Method: 'Conventional',
    Harvest_Date: '29 Aug 2018 to 5 Sep 2018',
    Variety: 'Arka Keshav',
    Pesticide_Residue_Index: 'Below EPA Tolerance',
    NoofOrdersProcessedforThisForm: '4',

  },
  {
    Farmer_Name: 'Deepak',
    Farmer_Location: 'Siddipet',
    Cultivation_Method: 'Organic',
    Harvest_Date: '29 Aug 2018 to 5 Sep 2018',
    Variety: 'Utkal Ava',
    Pesticide_Residue_Index: 'Below EPA Tolerance',
    NoofOrdersProcessedforThisForm: '3',

  },
];
```

Comment: Please share your list data and as well the event handler function code

Comment: onPicker = val => {
    this.setState({subject: val});
  }

Comment: check my edited code

Comment: You need to maintain value for each object same as `farmer_name` and `farmer_location`, add one more field for picker selected value.

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: Also please add onPicker code as well

Comment: i added in comment

Comment: The reason is because you are setting all the values to `this.state.subject` and when changing the value, then same value will be set to all of them. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the specified component, then remove `selectedValue={this.state.subject}`

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this is a workaround for you.

```
export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      subject:''
    }
  }

  onPicker = (val, itemIndex) => {
    console.log('onPicker value:', val, 'and index:',itemIndex)
    this.setState({subject: val});
  }

  render() {
    const myPicker = list.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Picker
          key={i}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.onPicker(itemValue, itemIndex)}>
          <Picker.Item label="Enter Quantity" value="Enter Quantity" />
          <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
          <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
          <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
          <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
          <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
          <Picker.Item label="6" value="6" />
          <Picker.Item label="7" value="7" />
          <Picker.Item label="8" value="8" />
          <Picker.Item label="9" value="9" />
          <Picker.Item label="10" value="10" />
        </Picker>
      );
    })

    return (
      <View>
        {myPicker}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export const list = [
  {
    Farmer_Name: 'Ramlal',
    Farmer_Location: 'Karimnagar',
    Cultivation_Method: 'Organic',
    Harvest_Date: '29 Aug 2018 to 5 Sep 2018',
    Variety: 'Arka Lohit',
    Pesticide_Residue_Index: 'Below EPA Tolerance',
    NoofOrdersProcessedforThisForm: '5'

  },
  {
    Farmer_Name: 'Ajit gopal',
    Farmer_Location: 'Warangal',
    Cultivation_Method: 'Conventional',
    Harvest_Date: '29 Aug 2018 to 5 Sep 2018',
    Variety: 'Arka Keshav',
    Pesticide_Residue_Index: 'Below EPA Tolerance',
    NoofOrdersProcessedforThisForm: '4'

  },
  {
    Farmer_Name: 'Deepak',
    Farmer_Location: 'Siddipet',
    Cultivation_Method: 'Organic',
    Harvest_Date: '29 Aug 2018 to 5 Sep 2018',
    Variety: 'Utkal Ava',
    Pesticide_Residue_Index: 'Below EPA Tolerance',
    NoofOrdersProcessedforThisForm: '3'
  },
];
```

Comment: check out my image.there if i select(enter) 7 from picker it is changing to all list.but i want to change that particular item of the list

Comment: i tried your code ..but still i am getting same problem

Comment: This should work, I tested it. Maybe you added something else? Did you remove `selectedValue={this.state.subject}` or change it?

Comment: no.i added same thing.after selecting that number it is showing again it is vanishing

Comment: i have removed selectedvalue

Comment: If you remove `selectedValue` then it wont set the value. Which means it wont call and change all of them. But only one of them. Also, what do you mean by "its vanishing"?

Comment: if i select 8 and it is printing and again it is coming back to enter..

Comment: Oh i see, I think you need to change to this `onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.onPicker(itemValue)}`

Comment: If you are still having trouble, then can you show your new full code?

Answer (score 1):

As @SGhaleb said, you were setting all values to `this.state.subject`

```
<Picker style={{ color: 'black' }}
   selectedValue={this.state.subject}
   onValueChange={(subjectValue, subjectIndex) => this.setState({ subject: subjectValue })}>
  <Picker.Item label="Enter Quantity" value="Enter Quantity" />
  <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
  <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
  <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
</Picker>
```